# How Do I Ignore Variable Not Defined Compile Error

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a module that I can copy into various MS Office applications that will return the current project/application/workbook/document path based on what application is running the VBA code.  My code (adapted from other code I found in searches) works, but when I try to compile it, I get a "Compile Error: Variable Not Defined" message because it doesn't recognize the property calls for the other Office Apps.  Is there some way to trick the compiler into ignoring these other app property calls, or something else I can do to get my module to compile?

```
Private Function GetActivePath() As String
' function returns the local path of the current active MSO application
' ** MSOffice applications only
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim errSub As String: errSub = "GetActivePath"

    Dim AppName    As String
    AppName = Application.name
    
    Select Case AppName
        Case "Microsoft Access"
            GetActivePath = AccessPath
        Case "Microsoft Excel"
            GetActivePath = ExcelPath
        Case "Microsoft Outlook"
            GetActivePath = "*** un-defined ***"
        Case "Microsoft Powerpoint"
            GetActivePath = PowerpointPath
        Case "Microsoft Project"
            GetActivePath = ProjectPath
        Case "Microsoft Visio"
            GetActivePath = VisioPath
        Case "Microsoft Word"
            GetActivePath = WordPath
        Case Else
            GetActivePath = "*** un-defined ***"
    End Select
  
    Exit Function

errHandler:
    Debug.Print errSub & ": " & Err.Description
  
End Function

Private Function AccessPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Access
    AccessPath = CurrentProject.Path
End Function

Private Function ExcelPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Excel
    ExcelPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Function

Private Function PowerpointPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Powerpoint
    PowerpointPath = ActivePresentation.Path
End Function

Private Function ProjectPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Project
    ProjectPath = ActiveProject.Path
End Function

Private Function VisioPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Visio
    VisioPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function

Private Function WordPath() As String
' will not compile unless current app is Word
    WordPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have the comand `Option Explicit` at the top? If so, you have to remove it

Comment: I fail to see how benefits of this approach outweigh the negative of not using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly where it's failing - which line is the problem here?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions; I was already considering removing "Option Explicit" from my module, but was just curious if anyone knew a better way.  Henrik's suggested "GetActivePath" function below using the "CallByName" function worked perfectly, and I was able to keep my Option Explicit declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can access PowerPoint's ActivePresentation variable (and presumably the corresponding ones for the other Office applications) as a property of the [Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Application).

Object properties can be accessed dynamically by name using the [CallByName function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function).

So something like this (not tested) should work:

```
Private Function GetActivePath() As String
    Dim DocPropertyName As String
    Dim Document as Object

    Select Case Application.Name
        Case "Microsoft Access"
            DocPropertyName = "CurrentProject"
        Case "Microsoft Excel"
            DocPropertyName = "ActiveWorkbook"
        Case "Microsoft Powerpoint"
            DocPropertyName = "ActivePresentation"
        Case "Microsoft Project"
            DocPropertyName = "ActiveProject"
        Case "Microsoft Visio"
            DocPropertyName = "ActiveDocument"
        Case "Microsoft Word"
            DocPropertyName = "ActiveDocument"
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 1000
    End Select

    Set Document = CallByName(Application, DocPropertyName, vbGet)
    GetActivePath = Document.Path
End Function
```

Alternatively, since we already know what all the possible property names are, we can make use of [late binding](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm) by declaring a reference of type `Object` to the Application object:

```
Private Function GetActivePath() As String
    Dim App as Object

    Set App = Application

    Select Case Application.Name
        Case "Microsoft Access"
            GetActivePath = App.CurrentProject.Path
        Case "Microsoft Excel"
            GetActivePath = App.ActiveWorkbook.Path
        Case "Microsoft Powerpoint"
            GetActivePath = App.ActivePresentation.Path
        Case "Microsoft Project"
            GetActivePath = App.ActiveProject.Path
        Case "Microsoft Visio"
            GetActivePath = App.ActiveDocument.Path
        Case "Microsoft Word"
            GetActivePath = App.ActiveDocument.Path
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 1000
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Henrik, your first suggested function using "CallByName" worked perfectly.  I was not aware of this function, and really enjoy learning new ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Check if you have the command `Option Explicit`at the top

Use **Option Explicit** statement to force explicit declaration of all variables. Attempting to use an undeclared variable causes an error at compile time. The Option Explicit statement is used at the module level only.